# PHP Associative Array in table iterate columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I get this array from a mysql query:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'MALE GENERAL WARD' (length=17)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'MG-8,MG-2,MG-4,MG-6,MG-7' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'FEMALE GENERAL WARD' (length=19)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'FG-4,FG-1,FG-2,FG-3' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'MOTHER CHILD WARD' (length=17)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'MC-2,MC-4,MC-5,MC-6' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'TWIN' (length=4)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'TW-A1,TW-A2,TW-B2,TW-C1,TW-C2' (length=29)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'NICU' (length=4)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'NICU-6,NICU-1,NICU-7,NICU-3,NICU-8,NICU-4,NICU-5' (length=48)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'CLASSIC' (length=7)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'CL-6,CL-8,CL-4,CL-5' (length=19)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'DELUXE' (length=6)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'DLX-5,DLX-6' (length=11)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'EXECUTIVE' (length=9)
      'vacant_beds' => null
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'AC GENERAL WARD' (length=15)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'AG-5,AG-1,AG-2,AG-3,AG-4' (length=24)
```

Now I want to display this array in html table.
I have tried this, where I can achieve it only partly.
I want the string part that is `string 'MG-8,MG-2,MG-4,MG-6,MG-7'` to be in separate columns.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($rows as $key=>$row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $key2=>$row2){
        echo "<td>" . $row2 . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

from which I get table like below

> MALE GENERAL WARD MG-8,MG-2,MG-4,MG-6,MG-7
>
> FEMALE GENERAL WARD   FG-4,FG-1,FG-2,FG-3
>
> MOTHER CHILD WARD MC-2,MC-4,MC-5,MC-6
>
> TWIN  TW-A1,TW-A2,TW-B2,TW-C1,TW-C2
>
> NICU  NICU-6,NICU-1,NICU-7,NICU-3,NICU-8,NICU-4,NICU-5
>
> CLASSIC   CL-6,CL-8,CL-4,CL-5
>
> DELUXE    DLX-5,DLX-6
>
> EXECUTIVE
>
> AC GENERAL WARD   AG-5,AG-1,AG-2,AG-3,AG-4

Comment: What string part? The one that you can explode by `,`?

Comment: yes. for example - `MG-8,MG-2,MG-4,MG-6,MG-7` and the like

Comment: Explode string by `,` but also you need to know max count of elements in a string.

Comment: do you mean implode by `,` in new array or explode. and how I will iterate in foreach `<td>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every item of your comma-separated string can be received by exploding string by `,`. But as every string can have different number of elements - first you need to find the value of max elements. Thus you need to iterate `$rows` twice - first find max count of elements and second - echo `td`s. So we can do this:

```
echo "<table>";
$new_rows = [];
$max_count = 0;
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    $elements = [];
    if (!empty($row['vacant_beds'])) {
        $elements = explode(',', $row['vacant_beds']);
        if (sizeof($elements) > $max_count) {
            $max_count = sizeof($elements);
        }
    }
    $new_rows[] = [
        'name' => $row['room_category'],
        'elements' => $elements,
    ];
}

foreach ($new_rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // echo name
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';

    // main part - items in elements we will wrap into `td`:
    foreach ($row['elements'] as $e) {
        echo '<td>' . $e . '</td>';
    }
    // if number of elements in `$row['elements']` is less 
    // than `$max_count` - we should add empty `<td>`
    if (sizeof($row['elements']) < $max_count) {
        echo str_repeat('<td></td>', $max_count - sizeof($row['elements']));
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: It's working absolutely fine. is `sizeof` is also a php function?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the needed key(in your case - `vacant_beds`) for further processing:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $key => $row2){
        echo "<td>" .
            (($key == 'vacant_beds')? implode("</td><td>", explode(",", $row2)) : $row2) 
        . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Numbers of `td`s in rows will obvously be different.

Comment: @u_mulder, yes, but it doesn't break the output. There would be a blank gaps, but *string part* which the OP wanted will *be in separate columns*